# get custom checkout field woocommerce in Email

Tags: php, wordpress

I added a field to the woocommerce checkout form which has the ID: # billing_wooccm13. Now I try to retrieve this value and to send it in sending the email. for that I have the following function:

```
function action_after_email_order_details( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

$order_id = $order->get_id(); /*sample order ID*/
$pickup = get_post_meta($order_id, 'billing_wooccm13', true);
$pickup_date = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'billing_wooccm13', true );

$ordered_date = $order->get_date_created()->format ('d-m-Y');
    echo '<table class="custom-table">';
 echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>Bestelnummer: WEB-' .$pickup_date.'</td>';
echo '<td colspan="2">Besteldatum: '.$ordered_date.'</td>';
 echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>Product</th>';
        echo '<th>Stuks</th>';
        echo '<th>Prijs</th>';
    echo '</tr>';



foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ) {
        // WC_Product_Simple Object
        // https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html

        // WC_Order_Item_Product Object
        // https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html

        // The WC_Product object
        $product = $item->get_product();    

       $attributes = $product->get_attribute('pa_formaat');

        // Get product name
        $product_name = $product->get_name();

        // Get product id
        $product_id1 = $product->get_id();

        // Get product id
        $total = $item->get_total() * 1.21;

        // Get variation id
        $product_id3 = $item->get_variation_id(); 

        // The quantity
        $quantity = $item->get_quantity();

    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><b>' . $product_name . '</b><br><b>Formaat: </b>' . $attributes .'</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $quantity . '</td>';
        echo '<td> &#8364; ' . number_format($total,2) . '</td>';


    echo '</tr>';

    }
$order_subtotal = $order->get_subtotal();
$order_BTW = $order_subtotal *0.21;
$total_order = $order->get_total();
 echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><b>Subtoaal:</b></td>';
echo '<td colspan="2"> &#8364; '. number_format($order_subtotal,2)  .' Excl. BTW </td>';
 echo '</tr>';

 echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><b>BTW:</b></td>';
echo '<td colspan="2"> &#8364; '. number_format($order_BTW,2)  .'</td>';
 echo '</tr>';

 echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><b>Totaal bedrag:</b></td>';
echo '<td colspan="2"> &#8364; '. number_format($total_order ,2)  .' Incl. BTW</td>';
 echo '</tr>';

 echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><b>Leverdatum:</b></td>';
echo '<td colspan="2">'. $delivery_date_formatted  .'</td>';
 echo '</tr>';



     echo '</table>';

}
add_action('woocommerce_email_order_details', 'action_after_email_order_details', 10, 4 );
```

Just if I apply at the top of this line:

```
$ pickup = get_post_meta ($ order_id, 'billing_wooccm13', true);
```

or

```
$ pickup_date = get_post_meta ($ order-> get_id (), 'billing_wooccm13', true);
```

both don't show a variable, is there anyone who knows how to get this visible in the email? For now I place this behind 'Bestel Nummer'

Answer (score 0):

If understood correctly you've added a `woocommerce_form_field`

If you want that filed in your email you can add this filter:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'your_order_meta_keys');
function your_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
  $keys['YOUR-FILED-TITLE-HERE'] = 'YOUR-FILED-NAME-HERE';
  return $keys;
}
```